# {PHP|MySQL} How to limit the duplicate output by 1?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello dear Stack Overflow !

I am making a table with two entries with PHP & SQL, in this case I get my `WHERE` value from a `$_GET['id']` and my SQL query is a Stored Procedure.

Here the result wanted (That's a manual preview (HTML)):
[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cinkF.png)

The PHP code of the table:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.3</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.4</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.5</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.6</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.7</th>
                    <th scope="col">Lv.8</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach($getValues as $effect): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $effect['effect_fastdesc']; ?></th>
                    <?php foreach($getValues as $lvl): ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($lvl['effect_id'] === $effect['effect_id']):
                            echo $lvl['effect_value'];
                        else:
                            echo '-';
                        endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here the output of my SQL:
[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmSkH.png)

and the SQL code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `gettest`(`weap_id` INT(11))
BEGIN
SELECT
    game_weapons.weap_name,
    game_weap_levelup.weap_level,
    game_weapons.weap_img,
    game_weapons.weap_desc,
    game_weapons.weap_tips,
    game_effectlist.effect_fastdesc,
    game_weap_levelup.effect_id,
    game_weap_levelup.effect_value,
    game_weap_levelup.weap_up,
    game_weap_levelup.weap_up_id,
    game_weap_levelup.pass_up_id 
FROM
    game_weapons
    INNER JOIN game_weap_levelup ON game_weapons.weap_id = game_weap_levelup.weap_id
    INNER JOIN game_effectlist ON game_weap_levelup.effect_id = game_effectlist.effect_id
    WHERE
        game_weapons.weap_id = weap_id;
END
```

As you can see `effect_fastdesc` give me the plain text but I would like to get it only 1 time on the table.
What happend currently:
[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LcYj.png)

I have already trying with the PHP `array_unique()` function, and don't have get it working.

Thanks you for any help you can give me, to understand how to do it.

Comment: use `DISTINCT` in your query https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: @YazanFouadAldbaisy that won't help as the level is different in each row. This requires a crosstab query, aka pivot table.